# java ldap connection pool timeout property not working as expected

Tags: java

In java LDAP connection pooling, I have noticed that the pool timeout setting property is not working properly. Given below are the ldap connection pooling logs while testing my application.

Following are the values for initSize & pool timeout properties
**com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.initsize = 10**

**com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout = 300000**

==================== LDAP LOGS ======================

21:38:48,480  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@e2d0ca3

21:38:48,480  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4f652edf

21:38:48,495  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@53bb2d84

21:38:48,558  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@45766ee8

21:38:48,558  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@703c62f5

21:38:48,573  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@279dd5ca

21:38:48,589  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@51c329b8

21:38:48,605  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@7ec5afb0

21:38:48,605  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3e3659c6

21:38:48,620  Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5bef29e1

**21:38:48,620  Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@332bf735**

**21:38:50,102  Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@332bf735**

21:41:05,661  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@e2d0ca3 expired

21:41:05,661  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4f652edf expired

21:41:05,661  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@53bb2d84 expired

21:41:05,661  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@45766ee8 expired

21:41:05,662  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@703c62f5 expired

21:41:05,693  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@279dd5ca expired

21:41:05,693  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@51c329b8 expired

21:41:05,693  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@7ec5afb0 expired

21:41:05,693  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3e3659c6 expired

21:41:05,709  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5bef29e1 expired

### **21:46:05,724  Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@332bf735 expired**

When the application requested for a first LDAP connection, 10 new connections are created (as init size is set to 10) along with the requested connection. After the used connection is released back to pool, it is not expired after 5 mins and same is the case with other 10 connections. I am not sure why the ldap pool timeout property is not working properly as I am getting different behaviors (some times connections getting expired in 1 min) while testing the same scenario different times. Has any one has experienced the same kind of behavior and any resolution for this?

Comment: I have found in the past that setting `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug=fine` disables the connection pool. Setting it to `all` does not.

Comment: After changing the value to _all_ it worked as expected on the first time. But on my second test all the new 10 connections have expired in 20 seconds. Copied the log below. Also, do you know why the recently released conn state is always set to 'busy'? Also, you can see that the first pool cleaning job ran 20 seconds after the conn is released.

05:57:23 Create and use LdapClient@a3adf0d

05:57:24 Release LdapClient@a3adf0d

05:57:24 release() LdapClient@a3adf0d busy

05:57:43 expire(): not expired LdapClient@a3adf0d idle

06:02:43 Expired LdapClient@a3adf0d expired

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after breaking my head for while I understand that the connection pool timeout property is working as designed and I have interpreted this in a wrong way.

My first LDAP connection pool was created at **16:36:04**. So, starting from that time the pool cleaning job will run every 5 minutes. So, lets say if new LDAP connections are created just few seconds or minutes before this scheduled job, they will be removed from the pool as part of the cleaning process. So, all the connections shown in the above log were expired at ***21:41:05*** even though they were created at ***21:38:48***.

So, don't expect that the LDAP connection will be removed from the pool only after 5 minutes of idle time.